# How to refer to MongoDB elements using Sinatra

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra

If I have a collection "answer" inside of db "math," and I have an element like this:

{ "_id" : ObjectId("540f4276905d8fe4a28b8751"), "item" : "a.", "answer" : "answer1" }

How do I render the "item" by itself in ruby/sinatra? For the "answer" elements I am using this code in sinatra:

```
<ul>
  <% @maths.each do |math| %>
    <li><%= math['answer'] %></li>
  <% end %>
    </ul>
```

But in some instances I just want to refer to single elements. I have been trying to use 'params' but this doesn't seem to work. Pretty basic question I know.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you means your code not work or you want to render that element to template?

Comment: hi, i just want to be able to render elements from mongodb, outside of the ruby code.

Comment: Why dont use ruby code? This template is rendered by ruby, if you skip ruby code, that template cant work.